# How to deserialize XML to a complete object in PHP

Tags: php, object, simplexml, xml-deserialization

i need some help here,  i found here many answers from how to access values from a object.
but no ways to deserealize an xml in an object usable, because when i try to use the function simplexml_load_string() from this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header />
    <soapenv:Body>
        <e:EnviarLoteRpsEnvio xmlns:e="http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws">
... SOME IMPORTANT XML ...
</e:EnviarLoteRpsEnvio>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

this loses some data that contains namespaces and show an incomplete result:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (2) { ["Header"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (0) { } ["Body"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (0) { WOULD SHOW A LOT OF IMORTANT XML HERE, BUT DONT. } }
```

i know that to acess this values, we need specify the namespace and use xpath like:

```
$obj_xml_lote->registerXPathNamespace('e','http://www.betha.com.br/e-nota-contribuinte-ws');
```

all right, but instead to access, i need a complete object for send to an webservice.

Comment: i need deserealize the xml to send the generated object through a __soapCall() for an webservice; but the webservice wait for an well formed object, in my case the object is incomplete... he dont have all the content sent through simplexml_load_string(), thanks.

Comment: have you tried http://php.net/soap?

Comment: yeah, i use the soap client to acess the webservice, but the problem is the object that i trying to send, he dont have all the content that the xml have. at the moment that simplexml_load_string parse the code, it constructs an incomplete object.

Comment: the problem is 'how to deserealize the xml completely', having this i solve my problem, but the only answers that i found shows something about access the values through xpath and namespaces. this way i only get parts of the object, this is not necessary.

Comment: it must be a limitation of php? therefore what I need, is the complete object, and not the values of the object. the webservice requires this as a paramenter.